# Magento2.4.2 how to use Page Builder

Tags: page-builder

I want to use Page Builder in the community version of Magento2.4.2, but this community version doesn't seem to come with Page Builder, what can I do

Comment: It will be much easier to upgrade Magento to version 2.4.3

Comment: My site cannot be upgraded to Magento2.4.3 due to other plugins